# How do I use the mounted function in VueJs 3 composition api?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I am trying out the composition api in vueJs 3. Unfortunately I don't know how to include my mounted code in the setup(). When I put the code into the setup, the javascript tries to access the not yet rendered DOM. Can anyone tell me how I have to rewrite this?

**Option api sytle (works)**

```html
<script>
export default {
    name: "NavBar",
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    methods: {},
    mounted() {
        const bm = document.querySelector('#toggle');
        const menu = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li');
        const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');

        // ...
        bm.addEventListener('click', () => {  
            bm.classList.toggle("active");
            overlay.classList.toggle("open");
        })
 
    },
}
</script>
<template>
    <header>
        <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
          <span class="top"></span>
          <span class="middle"></span>
          <span class="bottom"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
          <nav class="overlay-menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>      
    </header>    
</template>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. First of all, this not a good practice to get a html element via `document.querySelector()`, see [how to bind events in vue3](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events)

```js
// bad

<div class="button_container" id="toggle">...</div>

mounted() {
    const bm = document.querySelector('#toggle');
    bm.addEventListener('click', () => {  
        bm.classList.toggle("active");
        overlay.classList.toggle("open");
    })
}

// good
<div class="button_container" id="toggle" @click="toggleContainer">...</div>

methods: {
    toggleContainer() {
        ...
    }
}
```

2. If you really want to `document.querySelector()` in `setup()`， you can use `onMounted`

```js
import { onMounted } from 'vue';

export default {
    setup() {
        onMounted(() => {
             const bm = document.querySelector('#toggle');
             bm.addEventListener('click', () => {  
                 bm.classList.toggle("active");
                 overlay.classList.toggle("open");
             })
        });
    }
}

// or inside <script setup>

import { onMounted } from 'vue';

onMounted(() => {
   ....
});
```

But, just as [@kissu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu) commented, `ref` is a better way if you have to handle the html tag directly in vue

```js
<div
   ref="toggler">
   ...
</div>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const toggler = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
    console.log(toggler.value) // <div></div>
});
</script>
```

3. But none of the above follow the concept of Vue, which is [Vue is driven by data](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#what-is-vue).

Since you seem to create a click event listener which will effect the class in html, here is the Vue way:

```js
<template>
    <header>
        <div
          class="button_container"
          id="toggle"
          :class="{
             'active': isActiveBm
          }"
          @click="toggle">
          <span class="top"></span>
          <span class="middle"></span>
          <span class="bottom"></span>
        </div>
        <div
          class="overlay"
          id="overlay"
          :class="{
             'open': isOpenOverlay
          }">
          <nav class="overlay-menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <!-- ... -->
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>      
    </header>    
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const isActiveBm = ref(false);
const isOpenOverlay = ref(false);

const toggle = () => {
    isActiveBm.value = !isActiveBm.value;
    isOpenOverlay.value = !isOpenOverlay.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) are a more precise alternative to querySelectors.

Comment: Thanks DengSihan! I will refector and will bind in right way!

Comment: @kissu Thanks a lot for your kind suggestions, I've updated the answer, and hope it will help Max

Answer (score 0):

From the Vue docs Typing Component Template refs https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html

```
const theModal = ref<InstanceType<typeof Element> | null>(null);


onMounted(() => {
        const modal = new Modal(theModal.value!, {});

        modal.show();
});
```